# QT: Complete control "Owner drawing" over QListWidget rows

Tags: qt

I need a view that’s something like Skype’s contact view. List of names, with an image at their side, and some buttons that become visible as you select a row. Using **QListWidgetItem** does answer some of these requirements but is severely limited, by icon width and others.

One other thing that’s less of a priority — QListWidget scrolls in rigid steps. The scroll is not smooth and you can never see “half a row” like you can in Skype. It’s like QListWidget scrolls up and down in row-height steps, while Skype scrolls in single pixels. Much smoother and pleasing from a UX standpoint. I know Skype is QT. Are they using a different control for this?

How do I achieve complete control over the drawing of a row in QListWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better scrolling you can try to set [verticalScrollModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#verticalScrollMode-prop).